# ReactJS - ec2 server configuration issue

Tags: reactjs, amazon-ec2, webpack

I am facing some issues while run the reacj js in ec2 server.
I am using this command to run the server : npm start
Getting this warning and stop the server
WARNING in bundle.js from UglifyJs

```
"scripts": {
"start": "npm run build:prod",
"build": "webpack -d && cp src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --port 8080 --hot --host xx.xx.xx",
"build:prod": "NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config webpack.config.js --progress"
```

},

Webpack details:
[image]

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I am not able to run the server. If I am trying to run reactjs in ec2, it will shows this warning "WARNING in bundle.js from UglifyJs" and stops the server

Comment: Can you show us your webpack config?

Comment: Hi Matthew Herbst,
webpack details picture is added in the post section